# How to check if the app is starting for the first time?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm working on a new version of an app. In older version of the app some content has been downloaded from the web into the Cache-folder. This content is no longer valid in the new version, so I would like to delete some of these files first time this the new version of the app starts.

How can I check that the app is starting for the first time? I could use NSUserDefaults to store an indication, but is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I do is I check if the application has launched for the first time in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, and I store the current version of the application in the defaults.
What this does is at every update of the application, I can keep a track of what files need to be removed, and what files need to be stored for that version of the application.
Following is the code for that:

```
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kNOT_FIRST_LAUNCH]) {
    NSLog(@"fresh install = %d", (int)[self checkForFreshInstall]);
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:kAPPLICATION_LAUNCHING_FIRST_TIME];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
} else {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:kAPPLICATION_LAUNCHING_FIRST_TIME];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

This is the checkForFreshIntallMethod:

```
- (BOOL) checkForFreshInstall {
NSString *currentVersion = (NSString*)[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
NSString *prevVersion = (NSString *)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"prevVersion"];

if (prevVersion == nil) {
    // Starting up for first time with NO pre-existing installs (e.g., fresh 
    // install of some version)
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:currentVersion forKey:@"prevVersion"];
    // Save changes to disk
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    return YES;
}
else if ([prevVersion intValue] < [currentVersion intValue]) {
    // Starting up for first time with this version of the app. This
    // means a different version of the app was alread installed once 
    // and started.
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:currentVersion forKey:@"prevVersion"];
    // Save changes to disk
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    return NO;
}
return YES;
```

}

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: You can always do something like `NSArray* currentparts = [currentVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];` and `NSArray* perviousParts = [pervVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];` then compare the individual parts to determine if the version installed is greater than the pervious version. Hope this helps.

Comment: You could always use two integers for major and minor version (or three for #.#.#)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the NSUserDefaults approach.

```
if(the flag has not been set somewhere to say we've already done this dance){
 do the stuff we need to do 
 set the flag that we'll check again next time and skip this code next time
}
```